# Encrypt and Decrypt Using Crypto JS similar to openssl function in php

Tags: php, encryption, cryptojs

I am trying to encrypt and decrypt a string in PHP as well as in JS.

**PHP**

```
function encrypt_decrypt($action, $string)
{
    $output = false;
    $encrypt_method = "AES-256-CBC";
    $secret_key = '$6Za+?k}^`5q:f^@TSxy69gf7JcKuF!,';
    $secret_iv = '$6Za+?k}^`5q:f^@TSxy69gf7JcKuF!,';

    $key = hash('sha256', $secret_key);

    //  echo $key.'  '; // bc11b452cdf3f8155b5fd3e3711b1d0712638c613f33f5551b96d5bb37b490ae

    // echo strlen($key); // 64

    // iv - encrypt method AES-256-CBC expects 16 bytes - else you will get a warning
    $iv = substr(hash('sha256', $secret_iv), 0, 16);

    //   echo $iv.' '; // bc11b452cdf3f815

    if ($action == 'encrypt') {
        $output = openssl_encrypt($string, $encrypt_method, $key, 0, $iv);
        $output = base64_encode($output); // output is base 64 encoded
    } else if ($action == 'decrypt') {
        $output = openssl_decrypt(base64_decode($string), $encrypt_method, $key, 0, $iv);
    }
    return $output;
}

$encrypted = encrypt_decrypt('encrypt', 'alaks@123');

// echo "encrypted string is " . $encrypted; // Rko0Q0lsdnl3Ukp6RkI2bXA4STF6QT09

// echo "decrypted string is " . encrypt_decrypt('decrypt', $encrypted); // alaks@123
```

I am trying to apply the same secret_key and secret_iv and get the key and iv matching

**JS**

```
<script src="node_modules/crypto-js/crypto-js.js"></script>
<script>
  
    const secret_key = '$6Za+?k}^`5q:f^@TSxy69gf7JcKuF!,';
    const secret_iv = '$6Za+?k}^`5q:f^@TSxy69gf7JcKuF!,';

    const text = 'alaks@123';

    const key = CryptoJS.SHA256(secret_key).toString();
    const iv = CryptoJS.SHA256(secret_iv).toString().substring(0, 16);

    // console.log("key", key); // bc11b452cdf3f8155b5fd3e3711b1d0712638c613f33f5551b96d5bb37b490ae
   
    // console.log("iv", iv); // bc11b452cdf3f815
    
    function aesEncrypt(data) {
        let cipher = CryptoJS.AES.encrypt(data, key, {
            iv: iv,
            mode: CryptoJS.mode.CBC,
            padding: CryptoJS.pad.Pkcs7
        });
        return btoa(cipher.toString()); // convert the encrypted string to base64
    }

    function aesDecrypt(data) {
        let cipher = CryptoJS.AES.decrypt(atob(data), key, {
            iv: iv,
            mode: CryptoJS.mode.CBC,
            padding: CryptoJS.pad.Pkcs7
        });
        return cipher.toString(CryptoJS.enc.Utf8);
    }

    const encryptedText = aesEncrypt(text);
    const decryptedText = aesDecrypt(encryptedText);
    console.log('Encrypted Text - ' + encryptedText); // this encrypted text is different from php generated
    console.log('Decrypted Text - ' + decryptedText);

    // actual encrypted text = VTJGc2RHVmtYMSsvblljaUpsdElzQ2w4eVFsRnZHS01oR2g2WS8raTJLbz0=
    // expected encrypted text = Rko0Q0lsdnl3Ukp6RkI2bXA4STF6QT09

   
</script>
```

The generated encrypted text is also not consistent as in PHP. Below are the encrypted texts on every refresh

```
encrypted text generated = VTJGc2RHVmtYMTlISHlLdlBGdDB5Sitlb3pnY04wQjJtWWIwV0RCR1I1Yz0=
encrypted text generated = VTJGc2RHVmtYMS9XZXNyTzhMWkZqdEtpVkF1MURJeUdzUlhqUUlUcXRlTT0=
encrypted text generated = VTJGc2RHVmtYMTh3dHY0VDBBanhzbnltejV1K1MxV2FYb1ZXalJuTjJxZz0=
encrypted text generated = VTJGc2RHVmtYMTh3Z081YVViNnc3dCtZUlAvN05NZ09nRUh0blB0eTBpaz0=
```

My query is, what should be the CrptoJS setting, to get the same encoded output (Rko0Q0lsdnl3Ukp6RkI2bXA4STF6QT09), as in PHP

```js
const secret_key = '$6Za+?k}^`5q:f^@TSxy69gf7JcKuF!,';
    const secret_iv = '$6Za+?k}^`5q:f^@TSxy69gf7JcKuF!,';

    const text = 'alaks@123';

    const key = CryptoJS.SHA256(secret_key).toString().substring(0,32);
  
    const iv = CryptoJS.SHA256(secret_iv).toString().substring(0, 16);

    console.log("key", key); // bc11b452cdf3f8155b5fd3e3711b1d0712638c613f33f5551b96d5bb37b490ae
   
    // console.log("iv", iv); // bc11b452cdf3f815
    
    function aesEncrypt(data) {
        let cipher = CryptoJS.AES.encrypt(data, key, {
            iv: iv,
            mode: CryptoJS.mode.CBC,
            padding: CryptoJS.pad.Pkcs7
        });
        return btoa(cipher.toString()); // convert the encrypted string to base64
    }

    function aesDecrypt(data) {
        let cipher = CryptoJS.AES.decrypt(atob(data), key, {
            iv: iv,
            mode: CryptoJS.mode.CBC,
            padding: CryptoJS.pad.Pkcs7
        });
        return cipher.toString(CryptoJS.enc.Utf8);
    }

//**Edit 1: Added Code Snippet**
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/crypto-js/4.1.1/crypto-js.min.js"></script>
```

**Combined PHP and JS code**

```
    <?php
$text = 'alaks@123';

define('SECRET_KEY', '$6Za+?k}^`5q:f^@TSxy69gf7JcKuF!,');
define('SECRET_IV', '$6Za+?k}^`5q:f^@TSxy69gf7JcKuF!,');

function encrypt_decrypt($action, $string)
{
    $collectionInPhp = [];
    $encrypt_method = "AES-256-CBC";
    $output = false;
    $key = hash('sha256', SECRET_KEY);
    $iv = substr(hash('sha256', SECRET_IV), 0, 16);

    $collectionInPhp['secret_key'] = SECRET_KEY;
    $collectionInPhp['secret_iv'] = SECRET_IV;
    $collectionInPhp['key'] = $key;
    $collectionInPhp['iv'] = $iv;

    if ($action == 'encrypt') {
        $output = openssl_encrypt($string, $encrypt_method, $key, 0, $iv);
        $collectionInPhp['before_base64_encode'] = $output;
         $output = base64_encode($output);
         $collectionInPhp['after_base64_encode'] = $output;

    } else if ($action == 'decrypt') {
        $output = openssl_decrypt(base64_decode($string), $encrypt_method, $key, 0, $iv);
    }
    return [$output, $collectionInPhp];
}

$result = encrypt_decrypt('encrypt', $text);

$encrypted = $result[0];
$collectionInPhp = $result[1];
?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/pure/3.0.0/pure-min.css"
        integrity="sha512-X2yGIVwg8zeG8N4xfsidr9MqIfIE8Yz1It+w2rhUJMqxUwvbVqC5OPcyRlPKYOw/bsdJut91//NO9rSbQZIPRQ=="
        crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer" />
</head>

<body>
    <table class="pure-table pure-table-bordered">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>#</th>
                <th>PHP</th>
                <th>JS</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td>Secret Key</td>
                <td class="php secret-key"></td>
                <td class="js secret-key"></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Secret IV</td>
                <td class="php secret-iv"></td>
                <td class="js secret-iv"></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Key</td>
                <td class="php key"></td>
                <td class="js key"></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>IV</td>
                <td class="php iv"></td>
                <td class="js iv"></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Before Base64Encode</td>
                <td class="php beforeBase64Encode"></td>
                <td class="js"></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Encrypted</td>
                <td class="php encrypted"></td>
                <td class="js"></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Received in JS</td>
                <td class="php"></td>
                <td class="js encrypted"></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>After Base64Decode</td>
                <td class="php"></td>
                <td class="js afterBase64Decode"></td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
                <td>Decrypted</td>
                <td class="php"></td>
                <td class="js decrypted"></td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
    <script src="node_modules/crypto-js/crypto-js.js"></script>
    <script>
    const collectionInPhp = <?php echo json_encode($collectionInPhp); ?>;
    const encrypted = "<?php echo $encrypted; ?>";
    const base64Decoded = atob("<?php echo $encrypted; ?>");

    // const secret_key = CryptoJS.enc.Utf8.parse("<?php // echo SECRET_KEY; ?>");
    // const secret_iv = CryptoJS.enc.Utf8.parse("<?php // echo SECRET_IV; ?>");
    // const key = CryptoJS.SHA256(secret_key).toString().substring(0,32); 
    // const iv = CryptoJS.SHA256(secret_iv).toString().substring(0, 16);

    const secret_key = "<?php echo SECRET_KEY; ?>";
    const secret_iv = "<?php  echo SECRET_IV; ?>";
    const key = CryptoJS.enc.Utf8.parse(CryptoJS.SHA256(secret_key)).toString().substring(0, 32);
    const iv = CryptoJS.enc.Utf8.parse(CryptoJS.SHA256(secret_iv)).toString().substring(0, 16);

    function aesDecrypt(data) {
        let cipher = CryptoJS.AES.decrypt(data, key, { // test case 1
            iv: iv,
            mode: CryptoJS.mode.CBC,
            padding: CryptoJS.pad.Pkcs7
        });

        // return cipher.toString(CryptoJS.enc.Utf8);
        return cipher.toString();
    }
    const decrypted = aesDecrypt(base64Decoded);
    const collectionInJS = {
        base64Decoded: base64Decoded,
        encrypted: encrypted,
        key: key,
        iv: iv,
        secret_key: secret_key,
        secret_iv: secret_iv,
        decrypted: decrypted
    }

    document.querySelector('.php.secret-key').innerHTML = collectionInPhp.secret_key;
    document.querySelector('.js.secret-key').innerHTML = collectionInJS.secret_key;

    document.querySelector('.php.secret-iv').innerHTML = collectionInPhp.secret_iv;
    document.querySelector('.js.secret-iv').innerHTML = collectionInJS.secret_iv;

    document.querySelector('.php.key').innerHTML = collectionInPhp.key;
    document.querySelector('.js.key').innerHTML = collectionInJS.key;

    document.querySelector('.php.iv').innerHTML = collectionInPhp.iv;
    document.querySelector('.js.iv').innerHTML = collectionInJS.iv;

    document.querySelector('.php.beforeBase64Encode').innerHTML = collectionInPhp.before_base64_encode;
    document.querySelector('.js.afterBase64Decode').innerHTML = collectionInJS.base64Decoded;


    document.querySelector('.php.encrypted').innerHTML = collectionInPhp.after_base64_encode;
    document.querySelector('.js.encrypted').innerHTML = collectionInJS.encrypted;

    document.querySelector('.js.decrypted').innerHTML = collectionInJS.decrypted;
    </script>

</body>

</html>
```

**Value Comparison on PHP & JS**

[image]

Comment: What have you tried to resolve the problem? Where are you stuck? The output you've shown can't come from the code you've shared, as it does not print `encrypted text generated` anywhere, neither in the PHP part, nor in the JS part

Comment: _Small Note_ As your key is plainly visible to anyone with half an idea how a web page works, it does seem a waste of time encrypting anything

Comment: @NicoHaase I have commented the echo and console for better readability. I have tried removing pad and mode and available options of pad and mode in crypto js. I did refer to different SO questions and ended up with this cryptojs code

Comment: @RiggsFolly I have shared the code to be more readable. The key and iv wont be visible to the user in my regular code

Comment: You need to truncate the key in the CryptoJS code to 32 bytes and convert the key and IV to a WordArray using the UTF-8 encoder. The PHP code has many vulnerabilities, e.g. a hex encoded SHA-256 hash as key (which is silently truncated to 32 bytes) and a static IV instead of a random IV (where key and IV maybe even still use the same key material). Such a code should really not be used in practice.

Comment: Also, the code unnecessarily Base64 encodes/decodes twice, which is inefficient and without any benefit.

Comment: @AlaksandarJesusGene For one, there is no way to have your JS crypto code work _at all_ without shipping the key to the user's device where they will have full control and be able to view it if they desire. For two, IVs should be _random, unique per-message_, and are not necessarily secrets, so they're frequently packed into the first X bytes of a ciphertext. For three, IVs should _never_ be derived from the key in _any way_, or derived from any value, for that matter.

Comment: If you want to be able to encrypt something client-side without exposing sensitive secrets you should use asymmetric/public-key crypto. That said, SSL/TLS is exactly this, so the short version is "just have SSL on your site".

Comment: @all, this  is purley experimental purpose and not to worry on exposing the key. My task is to generate the encrypted string in crypto JS as generated in PHP. I am looking help on mode, padding and key length so that i get the output equal

Comment: Did you try to shorten the key to 32 bytes (`substring(0, 32)`) and parse the key and IV with the [Utf8 encoder](https://cryptojs.gitbook.io/docs/#encoders)?

Comment: Let me try. Should i truncate the key in php also to 32 characters. My task is to make sure, php and js encryption should result the same

Comment: No, in the PHP code the key is shortened implicitly. This does not happen in the CryptoJS code, which is why it must be done explicitly.

Comment: @Topaco I tested and the encrypted text is not the same as in php. I have updated the js code. To check the php code you can copy paste to https://www.proose.com/tools/php-fiddle to get the result.

Comment: Still missing is the conversion of key and IV into a WordArray using the Utf8 Encoder.

Comment: @Topaco I have updated the question with full code (encoding with php and decoding in js) The results were populated in html for your quick reference.

Comment: You are supposed to just convert the old key into a `WordArray`, so `CryptoJS.enc.Utf8.parse(key)`, that's all. The same applies to the IV. You're doing something completely different. Also, it is counterproductive to introduce a new code with new bugs/incompatibilities at this time. Use the old code (or adapt the new code to the old one), s. https://www.jsfiddle.net/5hfyosmx.

Comment: @Topaco It works perfect. Can you make the jsfiddle as answer so I could mark it as correct for future reference. Thank you very much.

Comment: You're welcome. I posted my comments as an answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the PHP code, the key is generated as SHA256 hash of the password `$secret_key`. `hash()` returns the result hex encoded by default, which is why the result consists of 64 hex digits, i.e. 64 bytes.
PHP/OpenSSL implicitly truncates the key length to 32 bytes according to the specified digest `AES-256-CBC`. CryptoJS does not automatically shorten, i.e. the shortening must be done explicitly.

The IV is generated as SHA256 hash of the password `$secret_iv`. Unlike the key, it is correctly truncated to the right size.

In order for CryptoJS to interpret the key material as key, it must be passed as WordArray. For this, the key must be converted using the UTF-8 encoder. The same applies to the IV.

```js
const secret_key = '$6Za+?k}^`5q:f^@TSxy69gf7JcKuF!,';
const secret_iv = '$6Za+?k}^`5q:f^@TSxy69gf7JcKuF!,';

const text = 'alaks@123';

const keyHex = CryptoJS.SHA256(secret_key).toString().substring(0,32); // Fix 1: Truncate the key to 32 bytes
const ivHex = CryptoJS.SHA256(secret_iv).toString().substring(0, 16);
const key = CryptoJS.enc.Utf8.parse(keyHex); // Fix 2: Convert key and IV to a WordArray using the UTF8 encoder
const iv = CryptoJS.enc.Utf8.parse(ivHex); 

function aesEncrypt(data) {
    let cipher = CryptoJS.AES.encrypt(data, key, {
        iv: iv,
        mode: CryptoJS.mode.CBC,
        padding: CryptoJS.pad.Pkcs7
    });
    return btoa(cipher.toString()); 
}

function aesDecrypt(data) {
    let cipher = CryptoJS.AES.decrypt(atob(data), key, {
        iv: iv,
        mode: CryptoJS.mode.CBC,
        padding: CryptoJS.pad.Pkcs7
    });
    return cipher.toString(CryptoJS.enc.Utf8);
}
const ciphertext = aesEncrypt('alaks@123');
const decrypted = aesDecrypt(ciphertext);
console.log(ciphertext); // Rko0Q0lsdnl3Ukp6RkI2bXA4STF6QT09
console.log(decrypted);  // alaks@123
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/crypto-js/4.1.1/crypto-js.min.js"></script>
```

---

The PHP code has some vulnerabilities and inefficiencies:

- No hex encoding should be used as key, but the actual value. Analogous for the IV.
- Instead of a static IV, a random IV should be applied.
- Instead of a fast digest, a proven key derivation should be used (at least PBKDF2).
- No double Base64 encoding/decoding should be applied.

Comment: for a long time ago, i can not found this. thank you brother. work like charm

Answer (score 1):

Based on @Topaco answer, below is the full working code.

```
    <?php
    $text = 'alaks@123';

    define('SECRET_KEY', '$6Za+?k}^`5q:f^@TSxy69gf7JcKuF!,');
    define('SECRET_IV', '$6Za+?k}^`5q:f^@TSxy69gf7JcKuF!,');

    function encrypt_decrypt($action, $string)
    {
        $collectionInPhp = [];
        $encrypt_method = "AES-256-CBC";
        $output = false;
        $key = hash('sha256', SECRET_KEY);
        $iv = substr(hash('sha256', SECRET_IV), 0, 16);

        $collectionInPhp['secret_key'] = SECRET_KEY;
        $collectionInPhp['secret_iv'] = SECRET_IV;
        $collectionInPhp['key'] = $key;
        $collectionInPhp['iv'] = $iv;

        if ($action == 'encrypt') {
            $output = openssl_encrypt($string, $encrypt_method, $key, 0, $iv);
            $collectionInPhp['before_base64_encode'] = $output;
            $output = base64_encode($output);
            $collectionInPhp['after_base64_encode'] = $output;

        } else if ($action == 'decrypt') {
            $output = openssl_decrypt(base64_decode($string), $encrypt_method, $key, 0, $iv);
        }
        return [$output, $collectionInPhp];
    }

    $result = encrypt_decrypt('encrypt', $text);

    $encrypted = $result[0];
    $collectionInPhp = $result[1];
    ?>

    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">

    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <title>Document</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/pure/3.0.0/pure-min.css"
            integrity="sha512-X2yGIVwg8zeG8N4xfsidr9MqIfIE8Yz1It+w2rhUJMqxUwvbVqC5OPcyRlPKYOw/bsdJut91//NO9rSbQZIPRQ=="
            crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer" />
    </head>

    <body>
        <table class="pure-table pure-table-bordered">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>#</th>
                    <th>PHP</th>
                    <th>JS</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td>Secret Key</td>
                    <td class="php secret-key"></td>
                    <td class="js secret-key"></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Secret IV</td>
                    <td class="php secret-iv"></td>
                    <td class="js secret-iv"></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Key</td>
                    <td class="php key"></td>
                    <td class="js key"></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>IV</td>
                    <td class="php iv"></td>
                    <td class="js iv"></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Before Base64Encode</td>
                    <td class="php beforeBase64Encode"></td>
                    <td class="js"></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Encrypted</td>
                    <td class="php encrypted"></td>
                    <td class="js"></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Received in JS</td>
                    <td class="php"></td>
                    <td class="js encrypted"></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>After Base64Decode</td>
                    <td class="php"></td>
                    <td class="js afterBase64Decode"></td>
                </tr>

                <tr>
                    <td>Decrypted</td>
                    <td class="php"></td>
                    <td class="js decrypted"></td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
        <script src="node_modules/crypto-js/crypto-js.js"></script>
        <script>
        const collectionInPhp = <?php echo json_encode($collectionInPhp); ?>;
        const encrypted = "<?php echo $encrypted; ?>";
        const base64Decoded = atob("<?php echo $encrypted; ?>");
        const secret_key = "<?php echo SECRET_KEY; ?>";
        const secret_iv = "<?php  echo SECRET_IV; ?>";
        const key = CryptoJS.enc.Utf8.parse(CryptoJS.SHA256(secret_key).toString().substring(0, 32));
        const iv = CryptoJS.enc.Utf8.parse(CryptoJS.SHA256(secret_iv).toString().substring(0, 16));

        function aesDecrypt(data) {
            let cipher = CryptoJS.AES.decrypt(data, key, { // test case 1
                iv: iv,
                mode: CryptoJS.mode.CBC,
                padding: CryptoJS.pad.Pkcs7
            });

            return cipher.toString(CryptoJS.enc.Utf8);
            // return cipher.toString();
        }
        const decrypted = aesDecrypt(base64Decoded);
        const collectionInJS = {
            base64Decoded: base64Decoded,
            encrypted: encrypted,
            key: key,
            iv: iv,
            secret_key: secret_key,
            secret_iv: secret_iv,
            decrypted: decrypted
        }

        document.querySelector('.php.secret-key').innerHTML = collectionInPhp.secret_key;
        document.querySelector('.js.secret-key').innerHTML = collectionInJS.secret_key;

        document.querySelector('.php.secret-iv').innerHTML = collectionInPhp.secret_iv;
        document.querySelector('.js.secret-iv').innerHTML = collectionInJS.secret_iv;

        document.querySelector('.php.key').innerHTML = collectionInPhp.key;
        document.querySelector('.js.key').innerHTML = collectionInJS.key;

        document.querySelector('.php.iv').innerHTML = collectionInPhp.iv;
        document.querySelector('.js.iv').innerHTML = collectionInJS.iv;

        document.querySelector('.php.beforeBase64Encode').innerHTML = collectionInPhp.before_base64_encode;
        document.querySelector('.js.afterBase64Decode').innerHTML = collectionInJS.base64Decoded;


        document.querySelector('.php.encrypted').innerHTML = collectionInPhp.after_base64_encode;
        document.querySelector('.js.encrypted').innerHTML = collectionInJS.encrypted;

        document.querySelector('.js.decrypted').innerHTML = collectionInJS.decrypted;
        </script>

    </body>

    </html>
```

[image]